# Multiple Featured Images Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

So my aim is to find a method of adding more thumbnails only for displaying on a custom post type, for example I wish to have a large image (not the same image) for a featured post and a different image for the default view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the end i followed this tutorial and it did exactly what i required to a T.

http://www.lifeonlars.com/wordpress/how-to-add-multiple-featured-images-in-wordpress

Comment: Its an old post but this may help others. There is a new plugin that allows you to add multiple featured image dynamically using graphical interface - http://wordpress.org/plugins/dynamic-featured-image/

Answer (score 2):

have you try this [add_image_size](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size)

why don't you use [custom post template plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-template/)

Comment: (not the same image) - sorry that just copies the same image i wish to have different visuals.

Comment: Xavier: could you please clarify your question

Comment: @Xavier: what about custom post template plugin.it's simple to have multiple featured image using this plugin

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution from online. I also customized some code. You can check this.

**Step 1** Download this library from this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/u8gfoy0r0mnk1wy/AAAxcwXGsqbcgvdSWVzAdMK6a?dl=0) and put beside `functions.php` ( theme root ).

**Step 2:** Copy this code below to `functions.php`.

```
/*
 * Code for Multiple Featured Image.
 * Multiple Featured image is only for your selected post type.
 */
require_once('library/multi-post-thumbnails.php');
if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) {
new MultiPostThumbnails(array(
    'label' => '2nd Feature Image',
    'id' => 'feature-image-2',
    'post_type' => 'your_post_type_name'
        )
);
new MultiPostThumbnails(array(
    'label' => '3rd Feature Image',
    'id' => 'feature-image-3',
    'post_type' => 'your_post_type_name'
        )
);
new MultiPostThumbnails(array(
    'label' => '4th Feature Image',
    'id' => 'feature-image-4',
    'post_type' => 'your_post_type_name'
        )
);
};
```

**Step 3** Check now.

Answer (score 0):

I can write entire code here, but clicking on this [tutorial link](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-add-multiple-post-thumbnails-featured-images-in-wordpress/) is much easier :)